# calculation of Balance using Credit debit in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have Dataframe like this

```
openingbalance = 10.00
    Date         Credit Debit 
0   01/09/2020   15.00   0.00 
1   02/09/2020   0.00    5.00
2   03/09/2020   0.00    5.00
```

I want DataFrame like this

```
      Date       Credit Debit   Balance
0   01/09/2020   15.00   0.00   25.00
1   02/09/2020   0.00    5.00   20.00
2   03/09/2020   0.00    5.00   15.00
```

First Balance value  is 25.00 because  openingbalance is 10.00 and first value is credit 15.00
so 10.00+ 15.00 ,if first value is debit then 10.00 - First Debit value

please help

Comment: SO is not a scripting website. You should demonstrate you put some effort in and got stuck at one point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtract Debits from Credits and use [`Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) on the result, then just add this to `openingbalance` to get `Balance`:

```
df['Balance'] = openingbalance + (df['Credit'] - df['Debit']).cumsum()
```

[out]

```
         Date  Credit  Debit  Balance
0  01/09/2020    15.0    0.0     25.0
1  02/09/2020     0.0    5.0     20.0
2  03/09/2020     0.0    5.0     15.0
```